# Can RequestPath be used with default files as with static files in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I serve static files from multiple different locations like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m1",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m1")
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m2",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m2")
        });            
    }
```

Each of these has an index.html and reaching them using something like http://localhost:5000/m1/index.html works fine.

I would also like them to be reachable like this: http://localhost:5000/m1/

I could of course hand code something but this is exactly what default files is supposed to be for so I would have expected the below to work.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m1"
        });
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m2"
        });               
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m1",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m1")
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m2",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m2")
        });            
    }
```

It does however, not work. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Do you want the `FileServer` middleware?

Comment: No, I do alot of other things aswell where I need more control than that allows but it would make the question way to rambly to include all of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out reading the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/DefaultFilesMiddleware.cs) for the default file middleware. You need to provide the same fileprovider to both middlewares so like this will work:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m1",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m1")
        });
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m2",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m2")
        });               
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m1",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m1")
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            RequestPath = "/m2",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\m2")
        });            
    }
```

Comment: You could even share the instances

Comment: Yeah, I do that in the real code that uses this so can confirm it works fine. Just didn´t want to deviate from the example code in the answer.